# Oracle exception on commit for batch

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a function that basically opens a DB connection, alters the autocommit to false, runs a batch update, resets the autocommit to the original value, and then closes the DB connection.

When I run the con.close() I am getting this...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection$CommitOption
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2383) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2407) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:373) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:373) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.5.11]
```

And ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar is in my WEB-INF/lib

This is my sample code (edited for some more context)

```
Connection con = DBConnection.openDBConnection(env);
if (null == con) {
    return false;
}
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

    for (ProcItem proc : listitems)  {
        ps.setString(1, junk);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Failed to create process insert batch");
    e.printStackTrace();
    success = false;
}

logger.trace("Finished creating batch update");

try {
    boolean ac = con.getAutoCommit();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    ps.executeBatch();
    con.commit();                     // this is the line throwing the exception
    con.setAutoCommit(ac);
    logger.trace("Finished running batch update");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Failed to execute process insert batch");
    e.printStackTrace();
    success = false;
} finally {
    try { if (null != ps) { ps.close(); } } catch (SQLException e) {}
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: how you add your batch to `ps`?

Comment: is that all your code?

Comment: I added some more context...

Comment: I dont know what happened but I restarted tomcat and now it works